# A problem with the output of a 4to1 mux made using 2to1 mux's in Modelsim

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

After a successful compilation and simulation using Modelsim of the code beneath, which is just a simple 4to1 mux built using two 2to1 mux's, I ran a waveform test to see what it would look like, the output was continuously in the U state regardless of the values the inputs, here is the code along with the results:

**a.** The code for the 2to1 mux:

```vhdl
entity mux2_1 is
port( a,b:in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
s:in std_logic;
e:out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0));
end mux2_1;


architecture wx of mux2_1 is

begin

process

begin
if(s='0') then
e<=a;
else
e<=b;
end if;
wait;

end process;
end wx;
```

**b.** The code for the 4to1 mux:

```vhdl
entity mux4_1 is

port( a,b,c,d:in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
       s1,s0:in std_logic;
       e :out std_logic_vector (2 downto 0));

end mux4_1;


architecture nj of mux4_1 is

signal t1,t2:std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);


begin

k1: entity work.mux2_1 port map (a,b,s0,t1);
k2: entity work.mux2_1 port map (c,d,s0,t2);
k3: entity work.mux2_1 port map (t1,t2,s1,e);

end nj;
```

Here's the console report just after simulating:

[image]

And finally, the waveforms, with the inconsistent output:

[image]

Comment: Errors: 4, Warnings: 2 - did you read them?

Comment: What are you doing with `c` and `d` in `mux4_1`? (Hint: nothing)

Comment: And what did you declare `j` for?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have just re-edited the code and reran the simulation, and, apparently, the problem still persists ( I've updated the post as well), I can't really seem to find a way to open the error reported in the transcript, a simple click on it does nothing, and a double click will redirect me to the very bottom of the transcript window.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Note the unlabeled process in architecture wx of mux2_1 has no sensitivity list but does include a final wait statement with no timeout clause and won't resume after suspending at the beginning of simulation. This design can't respond to changes on it's inputs (instance k3) in the following delta cycle.

Comment: @user1155120 Please forgive my inexperience for I'm quite new to this field. Thank you, your suggestion did  indeed solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error is due to the 'wait' statement in your 2:1 mux. Please remove it.

Here's a side note: use the wait statements as much as possible in the testbench only. As waits are non-synthesizable, you will come across a few errors.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest that you go read some VHDL code from others and try to understand what they are doing.  What you have is code that will do something, but not necessarily what you want it to do.  A big mistake people make when they start VHDL coding is to think it is software and that it can be programmed the same way as software; it isn't.  To get good at it you have to think in terms of hardware and what logic is being declared for your code.

The wait statement is a problem.  The only place a wait statement should be used is in a testbench since they cannot be mapped to logic cells. So what you want to do is to remove the wait statement and make a process sensitivity list (where, in this case you really don't even need it, but it is good practice).

```
p_MUX_2x1 : process (a, b, s)
begin
   if (s = '0') then
      e <= a;
   else
      e <= b;
   end if;
end process p_MUX_2x1;
```